# Sqlalchemy double association table?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I would like to create an association between a Dataset object and all Category objects through the Annotation table.

A Dataset contains a collection of Annotations. Each Annotation has a single Category. I want Dataset.categories to contain the unique set of Categories made up of all the Categories of all the Annotations in that Dataset instance. I have tried doing this with a double association table (`dataset_categories`), but it is not working. What is the right way to do this? Here is my code so far:

```
Base = declarative_base()

dataset_categories = Table('dataset_categories', Base.metadata,
    Column('dataset_id', Integer, ForeignKey('datasets.id')),
    Column('annotation_id', Integer, ForeignKey('annotations.id')),
    Column('category_id', Integer, ForeignKey('categories.id')))

class Dataset(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'datasets'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    annotations = relationship("Annotation")
    categories = relationship("Category", secondary=dataset_categories)

class Annotation(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'annotations'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    category_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('categories.id'), nullable=False)
    category = relationship("Category")
    dataset_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('datasets.id'))

class Category(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'categories'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False, unique=True)
    dataset = relationship("Dataset", secondary=dataset_categories)
    dataset_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('datasets.id'),
                        back_populates='categories')
```

Comment: Have you tried making all the columns in `dataset_categories` primary keys? In a lookup table, the foreign keys to the primary keys of the related objects should be primary keys themselves.

Comment: They are all primary keys

Comment: Yes, in their respective tables. I was referring to making the foreign keys in the lookup tables explicit primary keys in the lookup table as well.

Comment: Do you mean:

dataset_categories = Table('dataset_categories', Base.metadata,
        Column('dataset_id', Integer, ForeignKey('datasets.id'), primary_key=True),
        Column('annotation_id', Integer, ForeignKey('annotations.id'), primary_key=True),
        Column('category_id', Integer, ForeignKey('categories.id'), primary_key=True))

That did not work either

Comment: I suppose Annotation contains more information in your actual implementation, and has been simplified for the sake of [mcve]? If not, making `dataset_id, category_id` of annotations a key (unique) would prevent you from adding duplicates to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

Without the requirement that the association contain only the unique categories this would be as simple as using an [`association_proxy`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html). One option is to define the collection class to use as `set` when defining the relationship:

```
class Dataset(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'datasets'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    annotations = relationship("Annotation")
    categories = relationship("Category", secondary="annotations", collection_class=set)
```

On the other hand the secondary table of a `relationship` does not have to be a base table, and so a simple select from annotations can be used:

```
class Dataset(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'datasets'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    annotations = relationship("Annotation")
    categories = relationship("Category",
                              secondary="""select([annotations.c.dataset_id,
                                                   annotations.c.category_id]).\\
                                           distinct().\\
                                           alias()""",
                              viewonly=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think what I actually need is a `column_property`, and I think I might be able to use your latter query to get it. The Dataset class should only be able to access Annotation and Category objects through its relationship to Image. So maybe something like, `column_property(select([annotations.c.dataset_id,
                                         annotations.c.category_id]).\
                                         distinct().\
                                         alias()`?